# Selection of current limiting resistors to limit the current of ESD UART / I2C buses

Tags: resistors, esd

Since the connection to the I2C and UART buses goes through connectors, where there is a possibility of ESD formation, I would like to limit their current. As the protected device there will be a microcontroller (Atmega328P).

For these purposes, I want to use resistors. There is not much space for TVS diodes.

**Options:**

1. I2C bus speed - 100 kHz
2. The speed of the UART bus is 115200 baud.

Tell me, what values ​​of resistors should be used for these purposes? In order not to harm the signal.

I had a choice between 100 Оhms and 1 kОhms. Maybe you should choose a different resistance.

Thank you!

Comment: "There is not much space for TVS diodes". These can be just as small as resistors; for example DF2S6.2CT is similar to 0402 in size: http://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=22045&prodName=DF2S6.2CT (but the value is not suitable here)

Comment: What length of cable? How much capacitance the cable presents? How much crosstalk ìs expected in the cable to the sensitive I2C wires? What is at the other end of cable? What value are the I2C pull-up resistors, and are they before or after the series resistors?

Comment: To protect against ESD, you will very probably need more than *just* a resistor; a resistor and capacitor could do it (ESD events are short lived). The I2C might be a bit difficult running at 100kHz.